# Count the number of possible permutations of numbers less than integer N, given N-1 constraints

Tags: c++, algorithm

We are given an integer `N` and we need to count the total number of permutations of numbers less than N. We are also given `N-1` constraints. e.g.:

if `N=4` then count permutations of `0,1,2,3` given:

```
0>1
0>2
0>3
```

I thought about making a graph and then counting total no of permutation of numbers at same level and multiply it with permutations at other level.e.g.:

For above example:

```
             0
           / |  \
          /  |   \
         1   2    3 ------> 3!=6 So total no of permutations are 6.
```

But I have difficulty in implementing it in `C++`. Also, this question was asked in Facebook hacker cup, the competition is over now. I have seen code of other people and found that they did it using `DFS`. Any help?

Comment: Maybe I'm just being foolish, but **(1)** what does `0>1` mean? **(2)** why can't you figure out how to do it from looking at other people's code?

Comment: How big can `n` be? With that many restrictions, brute force backtracking might work.

Comment: 1) 0>1 means that index of 0 will occur before 1.
2)I have seen their code but it is quite difficult to determine the exact algorithm by seeing the code. Since it is quite complicated.

Comment: @IVIad: N may be large enough, but we can answer using modulo 1000007.

Comment: So that's just a factorial, right? How large is "large enough"? Still small enough that you can calculate it the usual way? (with some modulo operations throws in, of course)

Comment: NO the use of factorial is just for calculation of permutation. You can use your algo, or solve it without factorial. large enough means that the result we get may exceed the range of integers. Yeah that is why you have to use modulus.

Comment: Oh right, I understand the problem now I think.. it seems related to how many topological sortings of a graph you can have, where the graph is made out of the constraints.

Comment: probably you are right

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to use a standard permutation generator and filter out each permutation that violates the conditions. This is obviously very inefficient and for larger values of N is not computable. Doing this is sort of the "booby" option that these contests have which allows the less smart contestants to complete the problem.

The skilled approach requires insight into the ways of counting combinations and permutations. To illustrate the method I will use an example. Inputs:

```
   N = 7  
   2 < 4  
   0 < 3  
   3 < 6
```

We first simplify this by combining the dependent conditions into a single condition, as follows:

```
   2 < 4  
   0 < 3 < 6
```

Start with the longest condition, and determine the combination count of the gaps (this is the key insight). For example, some of the combinations are as follows:

```
   XXXX036  
   XXX0X36  
   XXX03X6  
   XXX036X  
   XX0XX36  
   etc.
```

Now, you can see there are 4 gaps: ? 0 ? 3 ? 6 ?. We need to count the possible partitions of X's in these four gaps. The number of such partitions is (7 choose 3) = 35 (do you see why?). Now, we next multiply by the combinations of the next condition, which is 2 < 4 over the remaining blank spots (the Xs). We can multiply because this condition is fully independent of the 0<3<6 condition. This combination count is (4 choose 2) = 6. The final condition has 2 values in 2 spots = 2! = 2. Thus, the answer is 35 x 6 x 2 = 420.

Now, let's make it a little more complicated. Add the condition:

```
   1 < 6
```

The way this changes the calculation is that before 036 had to appear in that order. But, now, we have three possible arrangements:

```
   1036  
   0136  
   0316
```

Thus, the total count is now (7 choose 4) x 3 x (3 choose 2) = 35 x 3 x 3 = 315.

So, to recap, the procedure is you isolate the problem into independent conditions. For each independent condition you calculate the combinations of partitions, then you multiply them together.

I have walked through this example manually, but you can program the same procedure.

Comment: +1 Any implementation suggestions? Your more complicated example complicates it quite a bit from an implementation point of view.